# Python Creating an installable program using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to use `pyinstaller` to create an installer for my python program, which is typically run as follows:

```
python -m <folder_name>
```

( I can't run by calling `__main.__py`)
Inside `<folder_name>` I have `__main__.py`, an empty `__init__.py`, and various folders containing python code.

I don't see any options in the pyinstaller documentation to support this type of program structure. Are there options for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to tackle this could be to create another python file which is something like this

```py
from <folder_name>.main import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then use `pyinstaller` on this file.

Also, make sure that you have an `__init__.py` in all the folders with python files so that they are treated like packages when performing a relative import.

Reference posts [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457809/pyinstaller-with-relative-imports) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348452/python-packaging-for-relative-imports)